# How to delete multiple ids in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51ee3966e4b056fe8f074f48"), "userid" : "66", "clientid" : "88", "deviceid" : "22", "timestamp" : "1374214822000"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51ee507ae4b056fe8f074f4a"), "userid" : "66", "clientid" : "88", "deviceid" : "22", "timestamp" : "1374214822000"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51ee51fee4b056fe8f074f4b"), "userid" : "66", "clientid" : "88", "deviceid" : "22", "timestamp" : "1374214822000"}
```

How to delete multiple ids in mongodb?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

By running remove once for each ID, or perhaps using in:

```
db.collection.remove( { _id : { $in: [
    ObjectId("51ee3966e4b056fe8f074f48"), 
    ObjectId("51ee3966e4b056fe8f074f4a"), 
    ObjectId("51ee3966e4b056fe8f074f4b") 
] } } );
```

Comment: mr.derick is there any data types in mongodb?

Comment: Yes, there are, but that has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: while inserting data into mongodb datatypes are not mandatory i think so..what is your opinion...

Comment: Is the same available with `NotIn` as well?

Comment: remove is **deprecated**!  Should be used `deleteMany`

Answer (score 33):

You can accomplish this by using the command [deleteMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/index.html).

```
const objects = [
    ObjectId("51ee3966e4b056fe8f074f48"), 
    ObjectId("51ee3966e4b056fe8f074f4a"), 
    ObjectId("51ee3966e4b056fe8f074f4b") 
];

db.collection.deleteMany({_id: { $in: objects}});
```